# Website available in standalone container, not in swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have Docker CE running on windows server 2016 with 2 images.

when I run these in containers, everything is fine.

```
docker run --detach --name Website1 --publish 94:94 webimage1
docker run --detach --name Website2 --publish 95:95 webimage2
```

I can access through browser on other PCs:

- http://host:94/page1.aspx
- http://host:95/page1.aspx

Now I want to run them in swarm.

I've gone through docker tutorial and 've set up docker-compose file, with services, port mapping. The setup has Website 1 of 1 replica, Website 2 of 2 replicas.

On `docker stack services websites` port numbers show up as follows.

```
Website1: *:94->94/tcp
Website2: *:95->95/tcp
```

but i can't access any of them with following url's:

- http://host:94/page1.aspx
- http://host:95/page1.aspx

I get - **This site can't be reached**

If I go back to one of my running containers, I see that the port number has a different format.

```
0.0.0.0:94->94/tcp (WORKING) VS *:94->94/tcp (NOT WORKING)
```

For initilizing docker swarm I used `docker swarm init` with IP address of the host on port 2377.

Here is how I deployed docker stack using compose file

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-stack.yml websites
```

**docker-stack.yml** file for reference.

```
version: "3"
services:

  website1:
    image: website1:latest
    ports:
      - 94:94
    depends_on:
      - website2
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
  website2:
    image: website2:latest
    ports:
      - 95:95
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
```

any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

many thanks

Comment: how many nodes have joined the swarm. Else are you trying to run both services in same node?

Comment: i originally had 2 nodes - one (worker) went down [falls off the network after a while]. it becomes unstable when it joins a swarm for some reason. so that just leaves me with 1 swarm (manager).

Comment: when my website wasn't accessible running in a service i did run it in a container at the same time. the single containerised version worked fine. the only difference is that the port mapping was listed as 0.0.0.0:94->94/tcp. i don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: so now is worker node attached or went down? also does worker node has website2 image?

Comment: to simplify matters, i'm just running one container in a service. "docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml website1". this comes up fine. replicas 1/1. drilling down into service shows no errors - status "running". yet on another PC i still can't access my website (http://host:94/webpage1.aspx". if i run the container independently, it works. just running in a service it's not accessible. when i do a "docker swarm init" i'm told there are 2 IP addresses, i have to pick one. i've tried both. one fails and i get a gateway error when starting up service.  the other IP address causes no issues.

Comment: thanks Mani. sorry if i've not provided enough information. forget about the swarm for now. i can't even get my container running in a service - which i suspect is the problem. so now i have one node running one service. except the website is not accessible when running in a service. fine in a container

Comment: ok chuck swarm as of now. how did you run the service please provide the entire command `docker service blah blah`.

Comment: getting closer ... "docker service create --replicas 2 --name contentlinksapi --publish mode=host,target=94,published=94,protocol=tcp contentlinksapi"  now my website is accessible on another PC in network on port 94. BUT -- only one or two of the containers in the service fires up. the second container complains that port already in use. Arrrghh ! this is hard work. i'm obviously missing some fundamental information about these things work - but where is this information ???

Comment: figured out the problem let me answer it.

Comment: if the answer solves your problem please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

From the conversations in the comments the problem is with the stack.

Docker stack supports only images for deployment and replicas. I believe your images are custom ones which are **neither in dockerhub nor in any private repo**. So when you try to deploy it in stack the service which is getting deployed in the worker node doesn't find such image and is unable to download it from repo. Hence the service won't start in worker node. It works perfectly in manager node because the image already exists there.

So, you have to **either set up a local/private registry or push the images to docker registry or else you can even copy the images from manager node to worker node** using `docker save` and `docker load` and then try using swarm and deploy in stack it will work.

Please note when working with swarm and registries, While deploying stack using `docker stack deploy -c composefile.yml test` you have to pass `--with-registry-auth` if you are using authentication for registries as `docker stack deploy -c composefile.yml test --with-registry-auth` else other nodes may not authenticate with the registry which will result in failure to download images if not found.

Also please note if you set up a local private repo without self signed certificate or with self signed certificate you may need to configure insecure registry. I've given reference of the same.

I recommend setting up a local repo without any authentication and certificates and access it by adding insecure registry in daemon.json file for testing purposes.

Now as per the last comment where you removed swarm and tried running docker service using

`docker service create --replicas 2 --name contentlinksapi --publish mode=host,target=94,published=94,protocol=tcp contentlinksapi`

It throwed port already in use because it tries to create 2 replicas in the same machine. Where the first replica binds to port 94 because of which, The second replica throws port already in use error.

For your reference.

1. [Deploy a registry server](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)
2. [Test an insecure registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)
3. [Docker service mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/) (check to know why services with two replicas deployed in same host on `docker service create`)
4. [Docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/#usage)
5. [Docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)

Comment: thanks so much for your detailed reply Mani. i will review and get back to you.

Comment: "It works perfectly in manager node because the image already exists there."

Comment: the problem is, it doesn't. to better explain the problem, i went through the mechanics of this tutorial: "https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/". the idea here is you start up your service - running multiple containers (running a website) - and you should then be able to access that website on the exposed port. docker will work out which container to run each request. but this doesn't work for me. the browser can't connect to the website - i'm on another PC to the docker manager one. hence my frustration. this seems so simple, it just doesn't work

Comment: i should add that the service starts up, all containers (replicas) are running - i look at their tasks and no errors.

Comment: I can't understand the exact problem. Better you run 1 replica of both services and try accessing. And the link that you have mentioned in comment is not accessible.

Comment: sorry, did not format URL correctly. [link](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3)

Comment: i tried 1 replica. same problem. the service is created, i container runs. everything looks fine. i used this command: docker service create --replicas 1 --name Website1 -p 99:94 website1_image   - so i should be able to access the website running in the container - http://webserver01:99/webpage1.aspx - it says can't connect.

Comment: btw - the image has port 94 exposed - and runs fine in a container.

Comment: You have to use ipaddress of the host manager machine to connect and not image name. For example if your manager machines's ip is 192.168.0.123 then you should be able to open it from web browser as 192.168.0.123:99/webpage1.aspx and obviously it won't work wiih  webserver01:99/webpage1.aspx.

Comment: hi Mani - i'm not using image name. webserver01 is the host manager machine - that's not it's real name; it was just as an example. i've tried host manager machine ip ... no joy. still can't connect.

Comment: Is your machine firewalled?

Comment: no firewall. if i run as a container, it works fine : http://hostmanager:99/webpage1.aspx. running as a service with 1 or more replicas, despite exposing/publishing same ports, nothing. can't connect to website. i've followed that tutorial to the letter - the only difference is that is for linux containers/i'm using windows. thanks; appreciate your input Mani

Comment: Please provide the tutorial link you ate referring to. And please provide docker swarm init command that you have used.

Comment: i used docker swarm init --advertise-addr [ip address]. i was originally given 2 ip addresses and it told me to select the correct one. i've tried both.

Comment: the only other bit of information i can provider: when i look at port mapping in (docker service ls or docker container ls) if it has this *:94->94/tcp - it doesn't work - if it has this 0:0:0:0:94->94/tcp it does work. when i run a single container, it has 0:0:0:0:94->94/tcp and i can access the website. when i run as a service, the container has *:94->94/tcp and the service has *:94->94/tcp - and  i can't connect to http://dockermanager:94/webpage.aspx

Comment: Any idea about why is it listing two ip address while ding docker swarm init?

Comment: i don't. it has one IP address for "Ethernet" and one for "Ethernet 2". Perhaps this is screwing things up. But as i said, i've tried both IP addresses and don't have success with either. might be the way to box has been set-up - not by me. but this is how a service should work yes ? i run service, publish port and website should be able to access - and docker decides which container to service request from the replicas ? thanks

Comment: if your system has multiple ip then you may need to provide which ethernet interface in --listen-addr and --advertise-addr. [Check this docker docs and try configuring.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_init/#--listen-addr "docker swarm init")