# Docker swarm container replicas are running but not able to hit the same in browser or with curl

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Am following docker documentation and trying to create replica of nodes using the link --> https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/

I have followed the steps as mentioned in the document but am not able to get the expected application response on curl or browser.

docker decompose file looks like below :

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: vigneshnithin23/restaurant:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
          constraints: [node.role == manager]
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

As per the documentation they are able to curl the URL. whereas am not able to do the same.

I had two IP address and initialised docker swarm with --advertise-addr - First wlan address

if I run the same code on single container am able to get the desired result.

I went through the question in below link, which was asked earlier but that didn't have proper answer

[Website available in standalone container, not in swarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349501/website-available-in-standalone-container-not-in-swarm)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to ask yourself whether your SpringBoot app would be able to
>   run in that constrained environment of 50% usage of the CPU per second
>   and 50M.

When you run that as a single container[9ms for startup] it is running in a non-constrained environment while in your stack file you are restricting it. So when you spin up the service it takes a longer time to warm up and get started.

Here is a screenshot of the same app by just changing the replica set to '1' and increasing the memory to 100M it takes around 900ms to serve the application & serve the response.
[image]

So try to fine tune those settings for resource constraints.